# How do you pass an environment variable from a script to a React Native file?

Tags: bash, react-native, environment-variables, npm-scripts

I feel like I'm doing everything right but I must be going wrong somewhere. I'm not using Expo or create-react-app. I'm on a Macbook.

First, I run `npm run start`, which runs a script. The script looks like this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ipAddress=$(ipconfig getifaddr en0)
echo "IP Address in config: $ipAddress"
export ipAddress

case "$1" in
    "emulator"|"e")
        sh ./scripts/emulator.sh && node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start ;;
    *)
        node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start ;;
esac
```

The important part to pay attention to is `ipAddress`. Here, echo prints out the correct address.

I ultimately want that variable to be used in a config file that looks like this:

```js
const ipAddress = process.env.ipAddress;
console.log("IP Address in config:", ipAddress);

const CONFIG = {
    ENV: 'debug',
    BASE_URL: `http://${ipAddress}:8080`,
    BUCKET: 'companymedia',
    STRIPE_KEY: 'placeholder_key',
    ITERABLE_PUSH_PLATFORM: 'SANDBOX',
    ITERABLE_PUSH_PLATFORM_ANDROID: 'AXA',
    ITERABLE_PUSH_APPLICATION_NAME_ANDROID: 'com.company',
    ITERABLE_PUSH_APPLICATION_NAME: 'com.company.Company.00009',
  };
  
  console.log("BASE_URL:", CONFIG.BASE_URL)
  module.exports = CONFIG;
```

When I run `npm run start`, the above logs don't print out.

I then access the `CONFIG` object later in the project in a lot of api requests using `BASE_URL`. They all work if I run this off my clusters on AWS. But when I try to run it locally this way, **`ipAddress` is undefined** so it can't connect to my backend and I get a `Network Request Failed` error, which makes sense if the url is bad. I can run it locally using `localhost`, but I want to use the ip address because it works consistently across all ios/android sim/emulators. Here is an example of one of the functions that uses the `CONFIG` object:

```js
export async function login(payload: Types.LoginCredentials): Promise<Types.Token | false | Types.ErrorStatus> {
  console.log("url:", CONFIG.BASE_URL)
  try {
    const res = await fetch(
      `${CONFIG.BASE_URL}/tokens/user/`,
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: getHeaders(null),
        body: JSON.stringify(payload),
      },
    );

    if (res.status !== 200) return res.status as Types.ErrorStatus;

    return JSON.parse(await res.text()) as Types.Token;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error",)
    return false;
  }
}
```

I tried passing the variables to the start commands. Here is one. Including `--env` resulted in `error: unknown option '--env'`, so I left that out. I also removed `export ipAddress` at one point:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ipAddress=$(ipconfig getifaddr en0)
echo "IP Address in config: $ipAddress"
export ipAddress

case "$1" in
    "emulator"|"e")
        sh ./scripts/emulator.sh && node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start ipAddress="$ipAddress" ;;
    *)
        node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start ipAddress="$ipAddress" ;;
esac
```

I also tried adding `node ./config/config.js` to the file like this, to make sure that file runs and sets the variables. When I did this, the logs in `./config/config.js` did print out, with the correct ip address. Maybe using `node` creates a new process so that's why the variable doesn't persist?:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ipAddress=$(ipconfig getifaddr en0)
echo "IP Address in config: $ipAddress"
export ipAddress

node ./config/config.js

case "$1" in
    "emulator"|"e")
        sh ./scripts/emulator.sh && node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start ;;
    *)
        node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start ;;
esac
```

I also tried loading the `config.js` file with another script with the `ipAddress` declaration bit before running `npm run start`, with and without those same `ipAddress` declarations in the start file. That command was `npm run config local` and the script looks like this. All the logs printed out correctly in this case too:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

error=""

case "$1" in
    "debug"|"d")
        cp ./config/debug/config.js ./config/
        ;;
    "release"|"r")
        cp ./config/release/config.js ./config/
        ;;
    "local"|"l")
        ipAddress=$(ipconfig getifaddr en0)
        export ipAddress   
        cp ./config/local/config.js ./config/
        node ./config/config.js
        ;;
    *)
        error="unrecognized environment: $1"
        printf "%s\n" "$error" >&2
        ;;
esac
```

I think the last approach didn't work because the variable didn't carry over when I ran npm run start, but I can't figure out why it doesn't carry over in the first case because it's all in the same process as far I as I can tell. What could be going on here? Thanks for anyone's input on this!

Comment: Have you tried using [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config)? It'll read .env files at build time. You could run your script to put the IP in the .env just before building, and it would be available at runtime.

Comment: Environment variables are always passed from parent process to child process. You can't pass them "to a file". You can however use commands (`sed`, `printf`, `envsubst`, ....) to dynamically create an variable definition in a file. If this is what you want, you need to show how the variable definitions in this file looks like.

Comment: what about `ipAddress=8.8.8.8 npm run start` ?

Comment: @Abe Thank you so much for your input! I read about that and may go for it but I'd prefer not to have to add any more packages if I can avoid it.

Comment: @user1934428 I appreciate you taking the time to comment! I will look into this. I supplied the files that are relevant, I'm not sure what else would be helpful, could you clarify? Those seem to be shell commands so I would have to use them in the start file I assume. Also not sure why you say you can't pass environment variables to a file? I'm clearly able to to do that because the `console.logs` in the `js` file are printing out the variable passed from the shell scripts. Maybe I just don't understand. Thank you!

Comment: @Fravadona Thanks very much, that is a possibility I could try. How is that different from passing the variables in my start script though? I'm trying to make everything simple and automatic if possible so I've stayed away from that approach for now. I may need resort to it though.

Comment: An environment variable lives in a **process** and a file is not a process. If a js process is priniting some variables to a log, these could be environment variables inherited from the parent process, or environment variables it sets on its own, or any internal non-environment variables which it reads from a file, for instance a configuration file. In this case, we just have strings in the file, which the process then slurps into its environment, but a string in a file does not have the property of being in an environment. The process is doing this interpretation.

Comment: @user1934428 Thank you for the explanation! It's still a bit murky for me but I think I just need time to digest it. I applaud your use of "slurps" here :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I investigated the `sed` command suggested by @user1934428 and had success! Using `sed` worked in both the `./scripts/config` file and the `./scripts/start.sh` file. The first line replaces `process.env.ipAddress` in `/config/config.js` with the hardcoded ip address. The second line does a similar thing with `BASE_URL`, the third line deletes `const ipAddress=...` and the line below it so a new variable isn't created every time the file loads/cosmetic reasons, and the fourth line just signals which file to perform these things in. Not exactly my original approach, but it gets the job done and is probably better. Thanks for everyone's help! I learned a lot, hope this helps someone else!

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

error=""

case "$1" in
    "debug"|"d")
        cp ./config/debug/config.js ./config/
        ;;
    "release"|"r")
        cp ./config/release/config.js ./config/
        ;;
    "local"|"l")
        cp ./config/local/config.js ./config/

        ipAddress=$(ipconfig getifaddr en0)
        echo "IP Address: $ipAddress"

        sed -i '' -e "s|const ipAddress = process.env.ipAddress;|const ipAddress = '$ipAddress';|" \
                  -e "s|BASE_URL:.*|BASE_URL: 'http://${ipAddress}:8080',|" \
                  -e '/const ipAddress =/,+1d' \
                  ./config/config.js
        ;;
    *)
        error="unrecognized environment: $1"
        printf "%s\n" "$error" >&2
        ;;
esac
```